# Sort array column where the last item equals the first of the next row

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, sorting, pyspark, null

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(      1,       'aa',  [None, 9]),
     (      1,       None,  [   9, 1]),
     (      1,       'bb',  [   1, 4]),
     (      1,       'cc',  [   4, 5]),
     (      2,       'ee',  [None, 2]),
     (      2,       None,  [   2, 8]),
     (      2,       'dd',  [   8, 7]),
     (      2,       None,  [   7, 1])],
    ['col_id',  'col_val',   'col_arr'])
```

Desired result - I want to group by `col_id` and return the last non-null item from `col_val`:

```
+------+-------+
|col_id|col_val|
+------+-------+
|     1|     cc|
|     2|     dd|
+------+-------+
```

The problem is the order column. It's an array where *its last element is repeated as the first element of the following row*. In the above example, the order of `col_id`=2 goes:
`[None, 2]`, `[2, 8]`, `[8, 7]`, `[7, 1]`.

Since `col_val` of `[7, 1]` is null, the result of `[8, 7]` should be returned, i.e. `'dd'`. The ordering always starts with null (None).

I've tried

```py
df = (df
    .filter(~F.isnull('col_val'))
    .groupBy('col_id')
    .agg(F.max_by('col_val', F.col('col_arr')[1]))
)
df.show()
# +------+---------------------------+
# |col_id|max_by(col_val, col_arr[1])|
# +------+---------------------------+
# |     1|                         aa|
# |     2|                         dd|
# +------+---------------------------+
```

It's not successful, as my order column does not follow a simple ascending / descending order.

Comment: i'm unsure if it is possible without an ordering field because even your array field does not have a linear order. how will spark know `cc` is the last row without a certain order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some decent thinking, I have found a working approach. The steps:

- collecting modified rows (as structs) for every `col_id` into lists
- creating a *map* for every `col_id` with first elements of the inner lists as keys
- sequential lookup in maps, "looping" through elements in array to create ordered lists
- removing nulls and extracting the last item

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W

df = df.withColumn('col_arr', F.transform('col_arr', lambda x: F.coalesce(x, F.lit(-9))))

inner_struct = F.struct('col_val', F.col('col_arr')[1].alias('last'))
c = F.collect_set(F.struct(F.col('col_arr')[0], inner_struct))
df = df.groupBy('col_id').agg(
    F.element_at(F.filter(F.aggregate(
        c,
        F.expr("array(struct(string(null) col_val, -9L last))"),
        lambda acc, x: F.array_union(
            acc,
            F.array(F.map_from_entries(c)[F.element_at(acc, -1)['last']])
        )
    ), lambda x: x.col_val.isNotNull()), -1).col_val.alias('col_val')
)

df.show()
# +------+-------+
# |col_id|col_val|
# +------+-------+
# |     1|     cc|
# |     2|     dd|
# +------+-------+
```